# Python interation and recursion

Tags: python, nested, iteration

I am currently learning python and while trying to find a way to compile data from IP registrations, I stumbled into nested dictionaries/lists. I have found a way to pull the data I wanted but this seems excessive but all of my attempts to consolidate the iteration has failed. Any documentation on this subject or some pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois

obj = IPWhois('8.8.8.8')
results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
for key, val in results.items():
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        if key == 'objects':
            objects = (val)
            for key, val in objects.items():
                if isinstance(val, dict) and key.startswith("ABUSE"):
                    abuse =(val)
                    for key, val in abuse.items():
                        if isinstance(val, dict):
                            contact = (val)
                            for key,val in contact.items():
                                if isinstance(val, list):
                                    if key == 'email':
                                        email = (val)
                                        value=(email[0])
                                        print (value['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will much clear,you should have a good look at obj's format

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois

obj = IPWhois('8.8.8.8')
results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
objects = results['objects']

for key, val in objects.items():
    if not key.startswith('ABUSE'):
        continue
    for ele in val['contact']['email']:
        print(ele['value'])
```